# Adding alerts to make a text box required using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-ui, frontend

I want to add alerts to point to a text box when it hasn't been filled in, in order to prompt the user that they can't move on until complete.
Below is the current jquery code I have included:

```
$(function() {
    $(".mytextboxes").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("This field is required");
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

This works and brings up an alert, however the alert does not close until *"OK"* has been clicked atleast 100 times. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

`$(".mytextboxes")` is the name of the class which includes a group of four text boxes.

Comment: why don's you use html5  form validation....

Comment: Have you tried removing `$(this).focus()`?

Comment: I removed the .focus and it works as it should, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you *focusout* you give the user a new alert, so when he tries to close a alert an event is raised where the user gets a new alert.